Impossible to authenticate in Copernicus with openeo using Spyder
I'm trying to autenticate in the Copernicus Dataspace environment using the python library openeo following the instructions provided in https://documentation.dataspace.copernicus.eu/APIs/openEO/Python_Client/Python.html
When I run the following script in Jupyter I can easily autenticate, but when I run it in my favourite IDE (Spyder 5.4.5) there is no way of getting the url for the autentication.
import openeo
connection = openeo.connect(url="openeo.dataspace.copernicus.eu")
autentication = connection.authenticate_oidc()

